# Fedora 17 MySQL Daemon Error

Tags: mysql, fedora

I am trying to run a local MySQL server on a Fedora 17 system. I initially installed MySQL through YUM, however when I run

```
mysql_install_db
mysqladmin -u root password 'MYPASSWORD'
service start mysqld.serivce
```

I receive an error in `/var/log/mysql`

```
121101 12:58:50 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/host.frm' (errno: 13)
121101 12:58:50 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Can't find file: './mysql/host.frm' (errno: 13)
```

After a little snooping I finally located the directory the daemon is attempting to access. No file of any kind `*.frm` is located. My problem is how do I generate this file. Is there a particular script I should run.

Answer (score 0):

Well it turned out to be a permissions error. I though I was loading `mysqld` with root permissions but it turned out I did that wrong. Anyway if anyone still has this problem the default location I found the mysql directory was located was `/usr/lib/mysql/mysql`. Simply execute

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /usr/lib/mysql/mysql
```

This should solve the problem.